# Bluetooth headset connecting but not playing music

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I bought 2 headphones yesterday and today both of them connect but don't play music... The sound of "connected" can be heard from the headphone but when playing music the song doesn't play on one device but works on the other device. The names are same.. Is that an issue? If yes, Plz tell me how to change the names.

> Device- Harman Infinity Glide 501.

> Bluetooth name(both)- Infinity Glide 501. (Both have different bluetooth address)